# The Pixel Shader unit expects a Sampler configured for default filtering to be set at Slot 0 [...]

Tags: directx11, hlsl, sampler-state

I don't understand this error. The full output being :

> The Pixel Shader unit expects a Sampler configured for default
>   filtering to be set at Slot 0, but the sampler bound at this slot is
>   configured for comparison filtering.

Here is how I create the sampler state.

```
// Skybox sampler description
D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC skyboxSamplerDesc;
ZeroMemory(&skyboxSamplerDesc, sizeof(D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC));
skyboxSamplerDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_COMPARISON_MIN_MAG_LINEAR_MIP_POINT;
skyboxSamplerDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
skyboxSamplerDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
skyboxSamplerDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
skyboxSamplerDesc.MipLODBias = 0.0f;
skyboxSamplerDesc.MaxAnisotropy = 16;
skyboxSamplerDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_EQUAL;
skyboxSamplerDesc.MinLOD = 0;
skyboxSamplerDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;

// Create the skybox texture sampler state
hr = g_d3dDevice->CreateSamplerState(&skyboxSamplerDesc, &g_SkyboxSamplerState);
if (FAILED(hr)) return false;
```

The bindings.

```
ID3D11SamplerState* samplerStates[2];
samplerStates[0] = g_SkyboxSamplerState;
samplerStates[1] = g_PixelDepthSamplerState;
g_d3dDeviceContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 2, samplerStates);
```

HLSL side.

```
SamplerState sbSamplerState : register (s0) {
    Filter = MIN_MAG_LINEAR_MIP_POINT;
    AddressU = CLAMP;
    AddressV = CLAMP;
    AddressW = CLAMP;
    ComparisonFunc = EQUAL;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your C++ code should specify the actual filtering state, your HLSL shader should not specify it, since everything written there will overwrite it (which is a feature of the effect-framework, not HLSL itself). This might be a bit weird, but works normally just fine. However, you are using a comparison filter on the C++ side (in your case `D3D11_FILTER_COMPARISON_MIN_MAG_LINEAR_MIP_POINT`) and not on the HLSL side. Since everything should work without the effect-framework (the part that specifies the state within the shader), you are not allowed to set the comparision filter in the C++ code, since the HLSL code expects a default (non-comparision) sampler state type. So you need SamplerComparisonState instead:

```
SamplerComparisonState sbSamplerState : register (s0);
```

If you want, you can still keep the filtering state in the shader, but in any case the sampler state type (comparison or not) needs to be the same, both in the HLSL code and in the C++ code.

Comment: I still have the same error with `SamplerState sbSamplerState : register (s0);`. The real question being : why does the pixel shader **expects** *default* filtering (and what does it mean actually) ? I don't want default filtering I want linear filtering. I don't have this error showing up if I set filtering to `D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT` C++ side but I don't want that. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I overlooked the type mismatches with the Comparison filter and did make some half-true statements about the nature of specifying the sampler state in the shader. I hope everything is correct and more clear now. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Wow cool. Ima verify this ASAP. I am not using the effects framework thing at all - is it mandatory ? What is it ? Is it not deprecated ? The only thing I am trying to achieve by the way is linear filtering, so the boundaring pixels of a texture coordinate are interpolated, unlike nearest pixel value where only the closest pixel is returned based on texture coordinates.

Comment: All right my bad. I was using `D3D11_FILTER_COMPARISON_MIN_MAG_LINEAR_MIP_POINT` when what I was looking for is actually `D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR` - I don't know what comparison filtering is supposed to mean.

Comment: Using the effect framework is not mandatory, but I thought that specifing the sampler state is a feature of it. How do you compile the shader?

Comment: Comparison filters compare all texel values they read with a given reference and perform filtering on the boolean results of the comparisions, rather than the texel values itself. It is super useful for shadow mapping. For sampling see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509696%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the different filter states [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarification. I am hot-compiling my shaders using `D3DCompile` from strings I append together (read from hlsl text-files). I am only creating a vertex & pixel shader at the moment.